# Cannot access instance variable in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a `Laravel + Vue` SPA project where I want to access the current logged in user's role in the vue page. The issue is that when I `console.log(Vue.prototype)`, I can see the `$role` variable that I define but when I `console.log(Vue.prototype.$role)` OR `console.log(Vue.$role)` it outputs `undefined`.

First, I fetch user's role in the `login` page and define a `meta` tag for it as below:

```
<?php
if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check())
    {
        $roleId = Auth::user()->role_id;
        $role = \App\Role::all()->where('id', '=', $roleId)->first();
    }
?>

//Here go the Body and Head tags

<?php if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check()) { ?>
    <meta name="role" content="{{ $role }}">
<?php } ?>
```

Then I set a `prototype` value on the `Vue` instance in `app.js` as below:

```
Vue.prototype.$role = document.querySelector("meta[name='role']")
                          .getAttribute('content');
```

After this, I want to access this `$role` variable in `router.js` where all the routes reside:

```
    {
        path: '/meetings/', component: MeetingsIndex,
        beforeEnter: checkUserRole(),
    },

    function checkUserRole()
    {
      console.log(Vue.prototype.$role); // Or console.log(Vue.$role);
    }
```

When I execute the above code, it outputs `undefined`, but when I `console.log(Vue.prototype)` then I can see the `$role` variable as below:

[image: Role]

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: uses [router-app](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-app)

Comment: One of three things is happening, and without more code it's hard to tell which one it might be (though you can easily perform some tests to check these): 1) The `Vue` instance in `router.js` is different than the one in `app.js`, 2) Something is overwriting the value of `Vue.prototype.$role` before you access it in `router.js`, or 3) The code in `router.js` runs before the code in `app.js`.